# Google Code Hosting vs Sourceforge

Tags: google-code, sourceforge

From your experience what is better SF.net or Google code?

To publish open source code? What is indexing faster in the search engine so  it has more exposure?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Of the two you asked, personally I'd say Google Code due to the homogeneous feel of all projects. A Google Code project looks like all other Google Code projects. It's very simple to find the information you need due to, again, all GC projects having the same layout, indication of project activity, ability to manage your GC project site through the revision control. It just gives a very basic, simple to understand interface for you and your community with powerful tools to manage it remotely.

Personally, though, I'd suggest github. It's everything I mentioned above but with the ability to use Git. Just about all of the code-esk archive sites give you the same features, just a different way to interface with the user.

Also, personal note, I just tend to stray away from Sourceforge because it always looks so busy no matter what page you're on. It's somewhat obnoxious and unnerving.

Answer (score 3):

I used to be on SF, but I moved all my code over to google.  SF is just too restrictive--they require approval for both setting up a project, and deleting a project.  Google gives you much more flexibility.  You can even reset your repository on Google if you need to.

Also SF is just hard to navigate and manage.  Google is simple and straightforward--like mentioned above it's simple to find the information you need.